# Springboot: Localhost:8080 results in Whitepage-Error instead of showing content

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, localhost, thymeleaf

I am trying to display a list of genes using Springboot and Thymeleaf. Database (genes, proteins etc.) and all methods(e.g. getIdentifier of a gene) are present and work. 
The project structure is:

[image]

My classes/html-files are:

Main:

```
package main;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

ApplicationController:

```
package gui.spring.controller;

import db.admin.DatabaseQuery;
import db.admin.local.DatabaseQueryLocal;
import db.io.FileReader;
import db.sample.Gene;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class ApplicationController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String root(Model model){
        DatabaseQuery query = new DatabaseQueryLocal();
        new FileReader(query);

        List<Gene> genes = query.getGenes();
        model.addAttribute("genes", genes);
        return "root";
    }

}
```

root.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <th:block th:each="gene:${genes} ">
        <p th:text="${gene.getIdentifier()}"></p>
    </th:block>


</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>1.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>SpringBoot</groupId>
    <artifactId>biosampledb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.6.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.7</version>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

So, we have had this in a course and sadly, no explaination to Springboot/Thymeleaf/Maven was given. I figured out most of it, I guess. What I want as **desired result** is, that upon calling "localhost:8080" in my browser, a list of gene Identifiers is displayed. Upon running the main atm, I get a Whitelabel error page.
I hope, this is all Code needed to fix my problem. What did I oversee/missunderstand?

Thanks :)

## UPDATE: New project structure

[image]

## UPDATE2: DatabaseQuery and DatabaseQueryLocal

This is the DatabaseQuery Interface (which was provided).

```
package db.admin;

import db.sample.Assay;
import db.sample.Gene;
import db.sample.Protein;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface DatabaseQuery {
    List<Assay> getAssays();

    List<Gene> getGenes();

    List<Protein> getProteins();

    void addAssay(Assay assay);

    void addGene(Gene gene);

    void addProtein(Protein protein);

    /**
     * Returns all Assays that used a Protein that is associated with the given gene.
     *
     * @param gene - gene to get the proteins
     *
     * @return list of associated assays
     */
    List<Assay> getAssaysByGene(Gene gene);

    /**
     * Returns all Proteins that have a measurement above or equal to 'meas' in any Assay
     *
     * @param meas - threshold value
     * @return A list of tuples (Pairs) where the Protein is left and the measured score from the assay is right
     */
    List<Pair<Protein, Double>> getAssayResultsByMeas(Double meas);

    /**
     * Return all Scores and assoc. Assays for a given Protein
     *
     * @param protein - protein to look up
     * @return List of Pairs of assays and results for the given protein on that assay
     */
    List<Pair<Assay, Double>> getScores(Protein protein);

    /**
     * Returns a protein by given identifier. Returns Optinal.empty if there is no protein with this name
     *
     * @param identifier - id of the protein
     * @return Optional protein
     */
    Optional<Protein> getProteinByName(String identifier);

    /**
     * Returns a gene by given identifier. Returns Optinal.empty if there is no gene with this name
     *
     * @param name - id  of a gene
     * @return Optional protein
     */
    Optional<Gene> getGeneByName(String name);

    /**
     * Returns a assay by given identifier. Returns Optinal.empty if there is no assay with this name
     *
     * @param name - id  of a gene
     * @return Optional protein
     */
    Optional<Assay> getAssayByName(String name);
}
```

DatabaseQueryLocal Class:

```
package db.admin.local;

import db.admin.DatabaseQuery;
import db.sample.Assay;
import db.sample.Gene;
import db.sample.Protein;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair;
//import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair;
//import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class DatabaseQueryLocal implements DatabaseQuery {
    private final DatabaseLocal db;

    public DatabaseQueryLocal() {
        this.db = DatabaseLocal.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Assay> getAssays(){
        return db.assayList;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Gene> getGenes(){
        return db.geneList;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Protein> getProteins(){
        return db.proteinList;
    }


    @Override
    public void addAssay(Assay assay){
        db.assayList.add(assay);
    }

    @Override
    public void addGene(Gene gene){
        db.geneList.add(gene);
    }

    @Override
    public void addProtein(Protein protein){
        db.proteinList.add(protein);
    }


    /**
     * Returns all Assays that used a Protein that is associated with the given gene.
     *
     * @param gene - gene to get the proteins
     *
     * @return list of associated assays
     */
    @Override
    public List<Assay> getAssaysByGene(Gene gene){
        Protein protein  = gene.getProtein();

        return this.getAssays().stream()
                        .filter(assay -> assay.getUsedProteins().contains(protein))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    /**
     * Returns all Proteins that have a measurement above or equal to 'meas' in any Assay
     *
     * @param meas - threshold value
     * @return A list of pairs where the Protein is left and the measured score from the assay is right
     */
    @Override
    public List<Pair<Protein, Double>> getAssayResultsByMeas(Double meas){
       List<Pair<Protein, Double>> results = new ArrayList<>();

       for(Assay assay: getAssays()){
           List<Double> measurements = assay.getMeasurements();
           List<Protein> proteins = assay.getUsedProteins();

           for (int i = 0; i < measurements.size(); i++) {
               Double m = measurements.get(i);

               if(m >= meas){
                   //results.add(new ImmutablePair<Protein,Double>(proteins.get(i), m));
                   results.add(new Pair<>(proteins.get(i), m));
               }
           }
       }

       return results;
    }


    /**
     * Return all Scores and assoc. Assays for a given Protein
     *
     * @param protein - protein to look up
     * @return List of Pairs of assays and results for the given protein on that assay
     */
    @Override
    public List<Pair<Assay, Double>> getScores(Protein protein) {
        List<Pair<Assay, Double>> results = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Assay assay : getAssays()) {
            List<Double> measurements = assay.getMeasurements();
            List<Protein> proteins = assay.getUsedProteins();

            for (int i = 0; i < proteins.size(); i++) {
                if (proteins.get(i).equals(protein)) {
                    results.add(new Pair<>(assay, measurements.get(i)));
                    //results.add(new ImmutablePair<Assay,Double>(assay, measurements.get(i)));
                    // http://www.javased.com/index.php?api=org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair
                    // https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair
                }
            }
        }

        return results;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a protein by given identifier. Returns Optional.empty if there is no protein with this name
     *
     * @param identifier - id of the protein
     * @return Optional protein
     */
    @Override
    public Optional<Protein> getProteinByName(String identifier){
        Optional<Protein> r = this.getProteins().stream().filter(p -> p.getIdentifier().equals(identifier)).findFirst();

        if(!r.isPresent()){
            System.err.println("DBQueryLocal: could not find protein by name: " + identifier);
        }
        return r;
    }


    /**
     * Returns a gene by given identifier. Returns Optional.empty if there is no gene with this name
     *
     * @param name - id  of a gene
     * @return Optional protein
     */
    @Override
    public Optional<Gene> getGeneByName(String name){
        return this.getGenes().stream().filter(p -> p.getIdentifier().equals(name)).findFirst();
    }



    /**
     * Returns a assay by given identifier. Returns Optional.empty if there is no assay with this name
     *
     * @param name - id  of a gene
     * @return Optional protein
     */
    @Override
    public Optional<Assay> getAssayByName(String name){
        return this.getAssays().stream().filter(p -> p.getName().equals(name)).findFirst();
    }
}
```

## UPDATE3: Execution log

[image]
Execution log from IntelliJ. the last three lines appear, when
calling "localhost:8080" in the browers. Process was terminated manually using the stop-button afterwards.

Comment: For staters stop mixing Spring Boot versions (2.0.3 and 1.4.6). next to that your project setup isn't following the required (and advised) setup. First of all your template directory is wrong and everything in the `db` package is ignored by Spring Boot (so if you use autos wiring there it won't work).

Comment: Thank you, I dont want to create confusion. Where do I mix it?

Comment: Your thyme leaf starter is from 1.4.6 (simply removing the version should fix it). Also it isn't about confusion it is about mixing stuff from versions that don't belong together.

Answer (score 1):

The default thymeleaf prefix (It is the property: spring.thymeleaf.prefix) for templates is: classpath:/templates/

If you move your root.html to src/main/resources/templates, it should work, if I don't miss anything else.